# Bootstrap tooltip's data-placement is not working when changed dynamically using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

When I open the page, the first time I hover the mouse cursor over the list of paragraphs (`q1`,`q2`,`q3`,`q4`), the `tooltip`'s `data-placement` attribute is set to be on the left side.

***Expecting:*** when I click on "Expand View" link, I'm calling a method `changePlacement` where I'm changing the scope value of `$scope.changeDataPlacement` to `'right'` , but `data-placement` is not changing to `'right'`...

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = ['q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4'];

    $scope.changePlacement = function() {
        $scope.changeDataPlacement = 'right';
        console.log($scope.changeDataPlacement);
        alert("data-placement@ right side:" + $scope.changeDataPlacement);
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div ng-app="myApp" align="center" ng-controller="myCtrl">
         <a href="javascript:;" ng-init="watchlistexpand = null;changeDataPlacement='left'" ng-click="watchlistexpand = !watchlistexpand; changePlacement();" title="{{ watchlistexpand ? 'Compact' : 'Expand'}} View">{{ watchlistexpand ? 'Compact' : 'Expand'}} View</a>
         <div ng-repeat = "item in items">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="{{(changeDataPlacement === 'left')? 'left':'right'}}" title="Hooray!">{{item}}</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Problem:

This issue isn't really related to AngularJS, it's rather because of the way jQuery and Bootstrap work. In your code, `changeDataPlacement` is getting updated with the value `'right'` when you click on "Expand View". And if you inspect the HTML, you'll see this `data-placement="right"`, which means it's rendered correctly by AngularJS.

The reason `data-placement="right"` is not taking affect is that Bootstrap's `tooltip` only considers the value of `data-placement` when it's initialized, which is on page load in your case. So even if you change the value of `data-placement` later programmatically (using Javascript, jQuery or AngularJS), it won't reflect this change on the `tooltip` itself.

## The Solution:

To solve this issue you could either destroy the `tooltip` and initialize it again with the new placement (not recommended). Or better yet change the already initialized `tooltip`, like this:

```
$('#tooltip').data('bs.tooltip').options.placement = 'right';
```

This will work on a single `tooltip`, to change it in all of them you could do this:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').each(function() {
    $(this).data('bs.tooltip').options.placement = 'right';
});
```

You could put this in your `changePlacement` function, and it'll work fine like in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/OmarEinea/pen/mpqoWM).

Or you could do it **The AngularJS Way**, which is to `$watch` the changes of `changeDataPlacement` and run this snippet of code whenever its value changes. Like this:

```
$scope.$watch('changeDataPlacement', function(placement) {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').each(function() {
        $(this).data('bs.tooltip').options.placement = placement;
    });
});
// Then in your function, you simply do this:
$scope.changePlacement = function() {
    $scope.changeDataPlacement = 'right';
};
```

Here's a another [codepen](https://codepen.io/OmarEinea/pen/XVzQjp) demonstrating the later implementation.